# TypeScript datastructure VueJS

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, vue.js

I bind some Array to my component like that

```
<my-component :filters="columnFilters"></my-component>
```

with

```
columnFilter: ["name", "surname", "hours"]
```

In MyComponent.vue I put **filters** as a props of type Array with a default function.

Now when I want to iterate over the items in **filters** with a simple forloop in a *computed property* :

```
for(var name of this.filter)
{
   console.log(name);
}
```

TypeScript don't let me because he see this.filter as any

**Edit**

The problem is that all my props in Vue.js are seen as type *any* even if they  are defined like that :

```
filter: {
  type: Array,
    default: function() {
      return [];
    }
  }
```

So the compiler of typescript don't compile because he can't see that filter is of type Array. Is there a way to let him understand that ?

Comment: `for in` in javascript over an array gives you the index of the array elements. Use `for of` (the newer ES6 syntax) or a regular for loop.

Comment: for of works for Array Type, I used a VueJS type with a internal type of array, but in real it's a observer collection and that's all the point I can't find any doc about this collection

Comment: You don't need to concern yourself that it's observed-- that's Vue wrapping the data to make it reactive.

Comment: If I do : 
for(var name of this.filters)
I have the exception *Type '(() => any) | ComputedOptions<any>' is not an array type or a string type.*

Comment: Maybe I need to change my compiler option

Comment: I'm not sure I can help you further; I don't know what you have defined to have those types, but it looks like you are passing an array of strings, and for..of should iterate that fine.

Comment: With es6 enable : *Type must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator.*

Comment: If you access a prop through a string like this: `this.filter["bla"]` then typescript can't infer the type and you will get the `no index signature` error. You can fix that in your `.d.ts` file using `keyof`.

Comment: Can you be more explicit or give me a link, i'm new in typescript, I think the main problem is that typescript can't see the type of `this.filter`

Answer (score 0):

Find a way to tell the type of my prop just by creating a new variable with the correct type and a cast inside the function where I use the prop :

```
let filters: string[] = this.filters as string[];
```

Solve the issue but still a bit ugly